# What is the term for managing programs and their relationship with students within a university?

Tags: university, exams, software, terminology, assessment

I'm developing a web application to help conduct assessments for a college. I have several components in the application:

| Component | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **Content** | Deals with the management of the content (questions that will be used in assessments later) for each course and allows organizing them into categories. |
| **Exams/Assessment** | Helps create tests/exams from the content/questions created in the **Content** component and then schedule and assign them to the right audience. |
| **Evaluation** | This component takes care of evaluating test responses, calculating scores and grading. |
| **Users** | Manages user accounts (students, teachers and administrators) in the system. |

However, there is one *unnamed* component.
What it takes care of is:

- Managing (adding, removing, updating) the programs offered by the college and the courses within these programs.
- It also controls the students' enrollments and defines how long they are valid. This includes both admission to a new program and promotion to a further academic term within a program.
- It associates students with one or more programs during a timespan (academic year).
- This component will help determine if a student's enrollment is current or is expired (of an academic term that has already passed by).
- In other words, it determines the relationship with the college programs and students by tracking them across multiple academic terms in these programs.
- The main entities in this module are programs, courses, students and their enrollments.

*Admission* does not really seem to be the right word here because it only represents part of what this component does. I have also considered *Program Manager* but could not come up with a better name. What would be the closest term that describes what this component is responsible for?

Comment: I don't think this question belongs here, perhaps on the English Language stack. However, how about "Administration"?

Comment: I idly wonder why you're developing a new web application to enter a market that's already so very crowded, including with at least one solution (Moodle) that's free (in both senses), open source, and highly configurable.

Comment: I think English.SE would consider this a "naming" question, which is not on-topic there. You could ask about it in their chat or meta, or possibly craft an on-topic question there after reading their site guidelines, but I don't think it's suitable for migration in the current form.